# Issue with DB Connectivity via SpotFire on a 64 bit machine

Tags: .net, reporting, spotfire

I am trying to establish DB connection to an ORACLE 10g DB. I have pasted the error information below. I am looking for some information on the issue.

System configuration:

- Windows XP SP2
- ARCH: AMD 64 bit
- TIBCOE SpotFire 64 bit

Error message: Could not open data source.

```
TargetInvocationException at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework:
Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. (HRESULT: 80131604)

Stack Trace:
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.ProgressService.ExecuteWithProgress(String title, String description, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.DataFormsUserActions.OpenData(DataSource dataSource, String progressOperationTitle, String progressOperationDescription)


InvalidOperationException at System.Data.OracleClient:
Attempt to load Oracle client libraries threw BadImageFormatException.  This problem will occur when running in 64 bit mode with the 32 bit Oracle client components installed. (HRESULT: 80131509)

Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OCI.DetermineClientVersion()
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection.OpenOnLocalTransaction(String userName, String password, String serverName, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean unicode, Boolean omitOracleConnectionName)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleInternalConnection..ctor(OracleConnectionString connectionOptions)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnectionOptions options)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.GetConnection(DbConnection owningObject)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.GetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.OpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OracleConnection.Open()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.DatabaseDataSource.<>c__DisplayClass4.<GetPromptModels>b__0()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Framework.ApplicationModel.Progress.ExecuteSubtask(String title, ProgressOperation operation)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.Import.DatabaseDataSource.<GetPromptModels>d__6.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSourceConnection.<GetPromptModels>d__2.MoveNext()
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Data.DataSource.Connect(IServiceProvider serviceProvider, DataSourcePromptMode promptMode, Boolean updateInternalState)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Data.Import.DataSourceFactoryService.OpenDataSource(DataSource dataSource, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
   at Spotfire.Dxp.Forms.Application.FormsProgressService.ProgressThread.DoOperationLoop()


BadImageFormatException at System.Data.OracleClient:
An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)

 (HRESULT: 8007000B)

Stack Trace:
   at System.Data.Common.UnsafeNativeMethods.OCILobCopy2(IntPtr svchp, IntPtr errhp, IntPtr dst_locp, IntPtr src_locp, UInt64 amount, UInt64 dst_offset, UInt64 src_offset)
   at System.Data.OracleClient.OCI.DetermineClientVersion()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Key error here is:

`BadImageFormatException at System.Data.OracleClient: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B) (HRESULT: 8007000B)`

The `BadImageFormatException` can occur if you are trying to load a 32bit DLL into a 64bit app, or vice versa.

From the sounds of it, either:

- You don't have a 64bit Oracle Client Driver installed, or
- The connection string is trying to load a 32bit Oracle Client Driver,  or
- the client driver is actually corrupt.

Answer (score 0):

It seems there is a way to force Spotfire to run in 32 bit mode, https://tibbr.tibcommunity.com/tibbr/#!/messages/66091 but I cannot figure out how. 
Does anyone know how to force spotfire to run in 32 bit mode?